# WKInterfaceController background image location

Tags: xcode, watchkit

I am making a WatchKit Table in a `WKInterfaceController`. I want the **ViewController** to have a background, as shown here:
[image]

I assign the background to the `InterfaceController` itself (not to the Table):

[image]

This works, except that the image is actually centred in the `Table`, not the `WKInterfaceController`, so that if I have a lot of rows I get this result (from Storyboard, the drawn boxes is what you see if you scroll on the watch to those rows):

[image]

The background image is located at the centre of the `Table`, and is only visible when the user scrolls to row 4-5 (green box).

Is it possible to keep the image centred in the `ViewController`, and let the rows scroll **over** the image, either in the Storyboard or in code?

Comment: If you assign the background image to the controller, then it's actually centered on the controller. The controller interface expands to accommodate the table with all its rows. 

Anyways, I do not believe it is possible to achieve the desired look you're going for. If you could scroll with the `group` element, then it would be possible, but since the scroll can only be attached to the `WKInterfaceController`, I do not believe there is a way to specify an image that is restricted to the viewing area, or one that goes along with the scrolling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Apple](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1112534#1112534) that is not currently possible.